# is the existence of sigma-algebra sufficient to ensure that any subset can be covered by the elements of the algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I've been trying to understand the central idea behind the measure theory: to define which subsets of $\Omega$ can be measured, where $\Omega$ is the domain of a function $f$. Once this is established then any function can be approximated by characteristic functions on these sets, which is used to define the integral $\int_\Omega fd\mu$.

What confuses me, when studying the literature, is that the tripple $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ i.e. (the set, the sigma-algebra of its subsets, and a measure function) is always used in the formulation of theorems, but it is somehow implicitly assumed that

Theorem(?): The very existence of a sigma-algebra guarantees that one can approximate (i.e. by covering) any subset of $\Omega$.

But such a theorem is probably incorrect without assuming additional properties of $\Sigma$. For example, the partition $\Sigma=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ is a sigma-algebra but can hardly approximate any subset.

Where the assumption that $\Sigma$ can in fact approximatively cover any subset in $\Omega$ comes from? For example, is it implied by the existence of a sigma-algebra on $\Omega$?

So, I wonder: is theorem(?) implicit in the definition of measure? and if yes, how is it guaranteed?

EDIT1: The background to the question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164919/help-needed-to-understand-a-theorem-from-measure-theory-approximation-by-really).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Measure theory makes explicit the distinction between two key concepts: measurability and measure. You may be  used to thinking of 
$$\int f(x) d\mu(x)$$
as a single object. Two things are needed for this integral to make sense: $f$ needs to be measurable with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ needs to be a measure defined on that $\sigma$-algebra. Note crucially that measurability of $f$ is not dependent on any kind of measure.

*Measurability* of a function $f$ is the property that one can distinguish the values that $f$ takes. This is perhaps easiest to understand in the discrete case. Suppose 
$$\Omega = \{\omega_1,\omega_2\}, \quad \Sigma = \{\emptyset,\{\omega_1\},\{\omega_2\},\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}\}.$$
What kind of functions $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are measurable with respect to $\Sigma$? Notice that $f$ can take at most $2$ values. If $f(\omega_1) = 1$ and $f(\omega_2) = 3$, then $f^{-1}(A) = \{\omega_1\}$ if $3 \notin A$, $1 \in A$ and $A$ is measurable. However, if $\Sigma = \{\emptyset, \Sigma\}$, even this function $f$ would not be measurable with respect to $\Sigma$. In fact, the only functions which are measurable with respect to the trivial $\sigma$-algebra are the constant ones.

A *measure* places weights on the sets $E \in \Sigma$. This allows for a notion of approximation. Measures $\mu$ for which $\mu(A) = \inf\{\mu(O) : A \subset O, O \text{ open}\}$ are called *outer regular*. Measures for which $\mu(A) = \sup\{\mu(K) : K \subset A, K \text{ compact}\}$ are called *inner regular*. Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is both inner and outer regular. Whether or not the measure is regular depends on the specific $\sigma$-algebra; simply being a $\sigma$-algebra is not sufficient.

To summarise: the coarseness or fineness of the $\sigma$-algebra allows for lesser or greater complexity of functions. There is no notion of approximation of sets in $\Sigma$ at this level; either a set is or is not in $\Sigma$, and $f^{-1}(A) \notin \Sigma$ for some measurable $A$ then $\Sigma$ is not rich enough to "support" $f$.

Measurability of a function $f$ is not related to the measure. The measure places weights on the $\sigma$ algebra. Whether or not it has certain approximation properties depends on the $\sigma$ algebra and the specific measure.

---

EDIT.

---

For concreteness, let us pass to the case
$$f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$$
where the image space $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the Borel $\sigma$ algebra $\mathcal{B}$ and Lebesgue measure $m$.

For any measurable $A \in \mathcal{B}$, define
$$f^{-1}(A) = \{\omega \in\Omega : f(\omega) \in A\}.$$

To first answer your questions, $f^{-1}([1/2, 3/2]) = \{\omega_1\}$, and $f^{-1}(A) = \emptyset$ if $1 \notin A$ and $3 \notin A$. This may seem strange, but it is exactly what the definition is telling you. What is the set of all $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $f(\omega) \in [1/2, 3/2]$? That set is the singleton $\{\omega_1\}$. This may be confusing because you are looking at a function which takes on finitely many values (2, in this case) on a continuous space. Hopefully what follows will help clarify this issue.

> Could you please explain why having a sigma-algebra structure on top of Ω is important in this context?

This is a good question. One reason is that having a $\sigma$-algebra structure allows one to talk about sets of a complexity corresponding to the function in question, on an arbitrary space. To illustrate my point, consider the $f$ given by the picture below.

[image]

Let us agree (despite my horrible picture) that $f : [0,4] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the function given by
$$1\cdot 1_{\color{red}{A}}(x) + 3\cdot 1_{\color{blue}{B}}(x), \quad \color{red}{A} = [0,1) \cup [2,3), \color{blue}{B} = [1,2) \cup [3,4].$$
Is $f$ so much different from the $f$ defined on $\Omega = \{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$? In some sense, yes -- the interval $[0,4]$ contains uncountably many points, while the whole space $\Omega$ only contains two. In another sense, no. The "complexity" of the function has changed little. The $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(f)$ generated by $f$ is defined to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra with respect to which $f$ is measurable. In this case, it turns out to be
$$\sigma(f) = \{\emptyset, A, B, [0,4]\}.$$
To see that this is a $\sigma$-algebra, observe that $A^c = B$, $A \cup B = [0,4]$, and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Thus $A$ and $B$ play the role of $\{\omega_1\}$ and $\{\omega_2\}$ respectively. Is $f$ measurable with respect to this $\sigma$-algebra? Once again, the key is that $f$ **takes on finitely many values**. Thus $f^{-1}((1,3)) = \emptyset$, while $f^{-1}([1,3]) = [0,4].$ Any other sets can be checked by hand depending on whether or not $1, 3 \in A$.

The thrust of this construction of measure is to make precise what you said:

> one classifies functions based on their domains, not on their images!

Indeed. This is the difference between Lebesgue integration and Riemann integration. Whereas to compute
$$\int_0^4 f(x) dx$$
with a Riemann integral, Riemann would have you subdivide many rectangles in the domain needlessly. Instead it is the image space that we should be subdividing. There are only two divisions to be made: $\{\omega \in [0,4] : f(\omega) = 1\}$ and $\{\omega \in [0,4] : f(\omega) = 3\}$, which are $A$ and $B$ respectively. Thus,
\begin{gather*}
\int_0^4 f(x) dx = 1\cdot m(A) + 3\cdot m(B) = 1\cdot 2 + 3\cdot 2 = 8.
\end{gather*}
To come full circle, let us place a measure $\mu$ on $\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$:
\begin{align*}
\mu(\{\omega_1\}) &= 2 \\
\mu(\{\omega_2\}) &= 2.
\end{align*}
Then, with $\Omega = \{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$ and $f$ defined as in the original post (pre-edit),
$$\int_\Omega f(\omega) d\mu(\omega) = 1\cdot\mu(\omega_1) + 3\cdot\mu(\omega_2) = 8.$$
Observe that the two integrals are handled in essentially the exact same way, because Lebesgue integration and the language of $\sigma$-algebras (i.e., breaking a function $f$ up depending on its *image*, not its *domain*) take into account the "complexity" of $f$ and adjust accordingly.

Indeed, the Lebesgue integral is defined by the above procedure. In the case of a function that takes on infinitely many values, such as $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$, we first approximate $f$ in a suitable sense by a function which takes on only finitely many values (called a simple function) and then take limits.

Comment: The example was extremely helpful. Thank you! Though I have a few questions, hope you do not mind helping me again. The expression $f^{-1}(A)$, and in particular the set $A$ in the expression it could be anything, right? If yes, what if I would take $A=[1/2,3/2]$, how would you reason then? It is strange that you are just checking $3\notin A$, and do not care about the fact that the function does not evaluate to the numbers in the intervals $[1/2,1)$ and $(1,3/3]$. This I do not understand. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Is it so that if $A$ contains neither $1$ nor $3$ then one takes $f^{-1}(A)=\emptyset$? Is this the implicit in the definition of $f^{-1}$? It seems that $f^{-1}(A):=\cup_{b\in B} b$ such that $B=\{b:f(b)\subset A\}$, where by definition if $f(b)\not\subset A$ then $b=\emptyset$?

Comment: "...There is no notion of approximation of sets in $\Sigma$ at this level; either a set is or is not in $\Sigma$, and $f^{-1}(A) \notin \Sigma$ for some measurable $A$ then $\Sigma$ is not rich enough to "support" $f$." I have not realized how powerful the concept is. So, one classifies functions based on their domains, not on their images!!! Could you please explain why having a sigma-algebra structure on top of Ω  is important in this context?

Comment: See edit for answers.

Answer (score 1):

You never need to use that $\Sigma$ allows you to approximate every subset of $\Omega$.

The key assumption is that the function $f$ that you work with is measurable. This means that $f:(\Omega_1,\Sigma_1)\to(\Omega_2,\Sigma_2)$ satisfies that $f^{-1}(A_2)\in\Sigma_1$ for all $A_2\in\Sigma_2$.

This is what allows you to ensure that the sets of $\Omega_1$ you need to consider to define the integral are not just approximated but are in $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: Hmmm... You turned my world upside down:) So for every image set I want to make sure that the inverse image (domain) belongs to a sigma-algebra. But what is the point then of defining all these classes of measurable sets, Lebesgue, Borel, etc? Isn't their ability to cover (with infinite precision as you emphasize) subsets in $\Omega$ (together with the fact that their volume is known) the very purpose of their construction?

Comment: so to rephrase the question: how the fact that a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ is a sigma-algebra $\Sigma$, ensures that any subset $S$ of $\Omega$ can be represented (covered up to an infinite precision) by elements in $\Sigma$?